# Can you update one project from another with Mercurial

Tags: mercurial

I'll try to explain my situation as concise as possible:

I have a template project that I use as a template (duh) when starting a new project.
This template project evolves, and sometimes I update it as I am working on another project.

So imagine that:

- Template project: template.file
- Project A: template.file & projectA.file
- Project B: template.file & projectB.file

(all projects are under revision control) Now when I change template.file in project A, I would like all other template.files in all other projects to update

I am on windows, using tortoisehg and I am relatively new at this versioning game. I suppose I would do this with branches? But then wouldn't the projectA.file and ProjectB.file also get added to the template project?

Comment: Do you start new projects by cloning the original template project?

Answer (score 2):

Here is something you could do:

Go into the template project and merge in project A, then prune everything you didn't want before committing. This is rather laborious and time consuming.

Then you can go into project be and pull from the template project and very carefully merge.

I would not do this for any number of reasons. First, it's messy and error prone. Secondly it results in both projects containing all the files of all the other projects, even if in the tip revisions those files are considered deleted. The history is still all there.

---

Here is another thing you could do:

Use `hg export` to export the change that modifies the template file from project A. Then use `hg import` to import that change into your template project.

Then pull from the template project into both project A and project B and merge.

This requires that you discipline yourself when modifying project A and always make modifications to template files their own change.

Alternatively, you can hand modify the exported change to remove extraneous changes.

---

Here is a third thing you could do:

Always modify template files only in the template project. Then you can pull from the template project into projects A and B and merge.

Comment: I suppose what I want is simply not possible (at least not without a lot of workaround tricks). Thanks for the answer anyway. Perhaps it'll come in handy one day.

Comment: @Brent: I think the `hg export` method would work better for you than your stated method of basically hand-rolled version control.

Answer (score 1):

There's nothing in Mercurial that will you out of the box with this, cleanly.

You could:

1. Stuff everything inside one big repository, just separate them into different directories
2. Use sub-repositories, meaning that Project A and Project B would reference the template project as a sub-repository
3. Just make a copy of the file in question to all the other projects/repositories

In either of these 3, there's nothing that will help you make sure a file inside each repository is in sync.

In the first case, you would have 3 distinct copies of the template.file, and updating one will not update the other two, and there's nothing in Mercurial that will help you with that.

In the third case, the three repositories are completely distinct and separate, which means changes in one does not propagate into the other.

The second case, however, can be done, but if you need to have a copy of the file inside the Project A/B repositories, you're back to the third case.

However, you can make the template project a sub-repository of Project A, and instead of making a copy of the file, out of the template project and into Project A, you refer to the one you have in the sub-repository.

This is the way Mercurial handles such things.

Comment: Those sub-repositories come close to what I want but not close enough. basically I want some files to be part of repository A and other files part of repository B but still be able to use them together as one project without having to worry about file/directory structures.

Comment: You can't do that, you either have to duplicate the files into all the repositories (which means different files, different histories, no clean merge capabilities across repositories), or combine them into one (which means one file, one history, and if you want multiple such files, back to square one.)

Comment: Oh well, I'll just continue to work with version numbers on the filenames for now until I can find a better workflow.